# DataGridView color rows

Tags: c#, datagridview, backcolor, datagridviewrow

Hi I am trying to change the data grid view rows back color. I managed to do this for one grid but for some reason another data gridview is not working.

The datagridviews are placed on a 2 different tabs using Tab Control. It works perfect for dgvTickets but is not working for dgvFXTickets. The cell index is correct as I checked it during debugging. Any help would be great.

```
        dgvFXTickets.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dgvFXTickets.DataSource = new DataAccess.FinanceData().getFXTicketsByDate(dateTimePicker1.Value).ToList();

        dgvTickets.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dgvTickets.DataSource = new DataAccess.FinanceData().getTicketsByDate(dateTimePicker1.Value).ToList(); 


        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvTickets.Rows)
        {
            if (r.Cells[8].Value.ToString() == "Completed")
            {
                r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            }

            else if (r.Cells[8].Value.ToString() == "Cancelled")
            {
                r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
            }
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewRow rFX in dgvFXTickets.Rows)
        {
            if (rFX.Cells[12].Value.ToString() == "Completed")
            {
                rFX.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            }

            else if (rFX.Cells[12].Value.ToString() == "Cancelled")
            {
                rFX.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try to use the debugger and check what is the value of _rFX.Cells[12]_ when your code enters the second loop

Comment: @Steve I did and the code is going into the completed and cancelled part but still not changing color.

Answer (score 1):

This happened because a databound control is not updated until the control is made visible.

I use this code on form load to prevent this problem:

```
Private Sub frmForm1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    For Each tabPage As TabPage In Me.tabTabControl1.TabPages
        tabPage.Show()
    Next tabPage

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The tab page should be selected before assigning color codes on it.

```
tabControl1.SelectedTab = 0; //select first tab page    
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvTickets.Rows)
{
        if (r.Cells[8].Value.ToString() == "Completed")
        {
            r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }

        else if (r.Cells[8].Value.ToString() == "Cancelled")
        {
            r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
        }
    }

tabControl1.SelectedTab = 1   //select second tab 
foreach (DataGridViewRow rFX in dgvFXTickets.Rows)
    {
        if (rFX.Cells[12].Value.ToString() == "Completed")
        {
            rFX.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }

        else if (rFX.Cells[12].Value.ToString() == "Cancelled")
        {
            rFX.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps